# Coordinate Geometry, Trapeziums

Tags: geometry

Say a trapezium ABCD, where A(2,3), B(4,9) and D(6,5) has an angle ABC of 90° and AB is parallel to DC

a) find the coordinates of C

b) the point E lies on BD such that BE:ED = 3:1. Find the coordinates of E.

Comment: Have you tried drawing it on graph paper or computer?

Comment: What kind of theorems can you use?

Comment: The coordinate of $C$ is $(7,8).$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x',y')$ be the coordinate of $C.$ Since $\angle ABC = 90^{\circ}$ so $C$ will lie on the straight line passing through $B$ and perpendicular to $AB.$ The equation of such a straight line is $$x+3y=31.$$ Since $C= (x',y')$ lies on this straight line so we have $$x'+3y'= 31.\ \ \ \ (1)$$ Again $C$ will lie on the straight line passing through $D$ and parallel to $AB.$ The equation of such a straight line is given by $$3x-y=13.$$ Since $C=(x',y')$ also lies on this straight line we have $$3x'-y'=13.\ \ \ \ (2)$$ Solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $x'=7$ and $y'=8.$ So the required coordinate of $C$ is $(7,8).$

Also the coordinate of $E$ is given by $$\left (\frac {3 \cdot 6 + 1 \cdot 4} {3+1}, \frac {3 \cdot 5 + 1 \cdot 9} {3+1} \right ) = \left (\frac {11} {2}, 6 \right ).$$